# Upgrade from VS2010 vb.net project to VS 2013 Upd 4 project on dotnet 4 causing issues with Service references

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, global, upgrade, service-reference

I have a WCF Service library built in Visual Studio 2010 targeting DotNet 4.0.

This WCF Service references an external service using service references to cause a windows service to do something when required. All references were created through Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

The service reference is defined as MyService.Interface and this is how everything references it in code.

This all works great and no issues.

Just installed a copy of visual studio 2013 Update 4 onto a virtual machine and imported a copy of the project.

Now, all my service references to this windows service in the code generated reference.vb file all are declared as global.MyService.Interface instead of just MyService.Interface.

I now have hundreds of errors stating the type global.MyService.Interface is not defined.

If I remove the root namespace of the WCF Project, this error is removed but the solution is then peppered with hundreds of other errors caused by removing the namespace.

What I am wondering is what was added to VS2013 to make all service references have global. added to the front of them in generated code (reference.vb), and is there a way to make it work like it used to so code generation doesn't include global. at the start of each reference?

I have tried setting the namespace for the service reference in reference.svcmap but that made no difference.

I have not yet tried svcutil as I don't want to have to go down a path of manually generating stuff that has worked for years just because VS2013 does something different now and there will be other developers who manage this and I don't want to have to have different methods of updating service references than they are used to just because of a version change in Visual Studio.

I have done some searching and found plenty of cases where people had to add global. to their references, but in this case its the reverse - it was automatically added and I want to remove it from generated code but cant find where to do it. I am hoping there is a check box that I can uncheck and it will magically go back to the way it was working.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

- SAMPLE * 
  Code from project opened in VS 2013 UPDATE 3. This code is generated as it always was...

```html
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Partial Public Class ExternalInterfaceServiceClient
        Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of BOHInterface.IExternalInterfaceService)
        Implements BOHInterface.IExternalInterfaceService
```

An the code that is generated for the same project in VS 2013 Update 4. The Global keyword has been added to the start of each reference of BOHInterface.IExternalinterface.

```html
    
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Partial Public Class ExternalInterfaceServiceClient
        Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of Global.BOHInterface.IExternalInterfaceService)
        Implements Global.BOHInterface.IExternalInterfaceService
```

The second one breaks everything and its the generated code in reference.vb.

Any way to get code in VS2013 Update 4 to generate the same as in VS2013 Update 3?

Incidentally - I am using VS2013 Update 3 until this is sorted :)

Regards

Rod.

Comment: If anyone is interested - the problem appears to be Windows 10 related. I just tried Windows 7 with VS2013 Update 4 and the problem doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until the 10041 build of Windows 10.  Try upgrading Windows 10 to the 10041 build.  I'm also using CTP 3 of Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Comment: Thanks - I am downloading the latest build 10041 and trying today. Thanks for the information. :)